# Can I loop through 2 Data Grid Views in 1 Button Click Event and Perform an Update?

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, foreach

I have an Person Table that has customers and salesman. Each customer is assigned to a salesman by a ParentID. i.e. The Customers Parent ID is the Salesmans' IndividualID. IndividualID is the Primary Key. I wrote a stored Proc that takes IndividualID and ParentID.
I need to loop through 2 datagrids both have checkboxes and then assign selected customer to selected salesman. (Basically saying, selected customers new ParentID is selected Salesman's IndividualID)
Anywya, I'm trying to just loop through 2 data grids in 1 button click event and get the ParentID and IndividualID. But I get rted squiggly lines under my variables in the second foreach loop. Here's my code:

```
protected void imgbtnReassgin_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //loop 1st gv

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCustomer.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkitemSelectorCustomers");
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        {
            GridViewRow r = gvCustomer.SelectedRow;
            int oldParentID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[2]);
            int oIndividualID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[0]);
        }
    }     // loop 2nd gv
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSalesman.Rows )
    {
        CheckBox chkBox =        (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkitemSelectorAllManagersandSalesman");
        if (chkBox != null && chkBox.Checked)
        {
            GridViewRow ro = gvReassignCustomers.SelectedRow;
            int oNewParentID = Convert.ToInt32(ro.Cells[1]);

            // Assign old ParentID to Salesmans ID//
            oNewParentID = oldParentID;

            // Call stored proc Update Customer with New ParentID//

            Individual ind = new Individual();
            ind.ReassignIndividual(oIndividualID, oNewParentID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `oldParentID`  and `oIndividualID` variables are declared inside the first foreach and accessed in the second one, which is not allowed, because their scope is inside the first foreach.

Try declare them outside the foreach loops. The code will compile, but I'm not sure it will solve your updates.

Comment: Thank you. I movee them out. Code compiles, however I get this error:    Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on this line:     int oldParentID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[3]);

Comment: SelectedRow migth be null. Instead of playing with Cells[i], better add hidden fields and store the ids in their values or use GridView's DataKeys property.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same variable name in the second nested loop `GridViewRow row` if you have nested loops they can´t have the same variable name.

Comment: I understand but that has not been giving me an error for some reason.